# Read access violation when using %s format specifier

Tags: arrays, c

I've been trying to write a program that takes a string as a input, and output will be the same string written in morse code, however in getting reading access violation, while using %s format specifier with *(mors + i).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

void code(char litery[], const char* mors) {
    char arr[256];
    printf("string to be coded:\n");
    fgets(arr, 256, stdin);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < strlen(arr); ++counter) {
        if (arr[counter] == ' ') {
            printf(" ");
        }
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 36; ++i) {
            if (arr[counter] == litery[i]) {
                printf("%s", *(mors + i));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

int main() {
    char litery[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
    const char* mors[] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----" };
    code(litery, *mors);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main problems in your code -

**First**, here you are passing the first string of `mors` string array -

```
code(litery, *mors);
```

`*mors` is same as `more[0]`, i.e. here you are passing the string pointed by pointer at `0`<sup>th</sup> index, which is string `".-"`. Instead, you should pass whole `mors` array.

It should be

```
code(litery, mors);
             ^^^^
```

and you have to modify the type of second parameter of `code()` function as well to receive `mors` string array, like this

```
void code(char litery[], const char** mors)
                                   ^^
```

**Second**, instead of comparing `arr[i]` with `litery[i]`, you should compare `arr` array element at `counter` index with `litery[i]`

```
            if (arr[counter] == litery[i]) {
                    ^^^^^^^
```

***By the time I posted this answer, OP has edited the question and rectified the `Second` problem, I pointed out, in his code.***

Additional,

When user give input and press `ENTER` key, `fgets()` consider the newline character as a valid character and includes it in the input string given by the user. Remove the trailing newline character from the input buffer `arr` before processing it, like this:

```
arr[strcspn(arr, "\n")] = 0;
```

Comment: yes, you're totally right, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The code you gave us has lots of problems in it. I don't know where to start but i am going to skip all the explanation and here is your working code but i would not prefer to use your style of input and memory management :P

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

void code(const char** litery[], const char** mors) {
    char arr[256];
    printf("string to be coded:\n");
    fgets(arr, 256, stdin);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < strlen(arr); ++counter) {
        if (arr[counter] == ' ') {
            printf(" ");
        }
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 36; ++i) {
            if (arr[counter] == litery[i]) {                    
                printf("%s", (mors[i]));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

int main() {
    const char* litery[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
    const char* mors[] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----" };
    code(&litery, &mors);
}
```